# Отправка данных jquery

Tags: jquery

Сейчас пытался отправить данные:

```
var num = 5;
var text = searchvalue;

data: {"num": num, "text": text},
```

Где searchvalue это любое текстовое значение.

Однако при отправке скипт не работает, но если ввести числовое значение, то все работает.

Как мне отправлять текстовые значения?

Comment: код постить надо а не рассказывать что у меня вот там то там то не работает, полностью код выложите и я вас сразу ткну в ошибку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Куда отправлять?
Возможно причины в этом:

```
var text = 'searchvalue';
data:{num: num, text: text}
```